# scipy.stats : bandwidth factor in gaussian kernel density estimator

Tags: r, numpy, scipy, scipy.stats

I generated a 2D gaussian distribution (uncorrelated datas)

```
dist2=np.array([np.random.normal(loc=10,scale=3, size=50000),np.random.normal(loc=5,scale=2, size=50000)])
```

I calculated the covariance matrix divided by bandwidth factor because the covariance attribute is *The covariance matrix of dataset, scaled by the calculated bandwidth (kde.factor)* (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)

```
from scipy.stats import kde
# Use a kernel density estimator to produce local-counts in this space, and grid them to plot.
k = kde.gaussian_kde(dist2)
k.covariance/k.factor
```

Diagonal elements are not the square of the sigmas as expected.

I think there is something I have not understood on this bandwidth factor.

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks for help.

Comment: The covariance factor is implemented here so that `k.covariance/k.factor**2` ~ `np.cov(dist2)`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630515/getting-bandwidth-used-by-scipys-gaussian-kde-function

Comment: @MaxPierini. Thanks for comment that is an answer.

Comment: Added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde` the covariance factor is implemented so that `k.covariance / k.factor**2` is ~ to `np.cov(dist2)`.

Se here for details [Getting bandwidth used by SciPy's gaussian_kde function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630515/getting-bandwidth-used-by-scipys-gaussian-kde-function)